# Sort two-dimensional list on predicate in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell

I have a list of lists of tuples (`[[(Int, Custom)]]`) and I would like to sort the outer lists by comparing the integers with each other. It should behave just like a normal two-dimensional sort, i.e. it should sort the first by the first list items, then by the second items and so on - but compare the first parts instead of the whole tuples.

For a one-dimensional list I would've used `sortBy (comparing fst)`, but I'm totally lost with having them wrapped in another list. I know it would work automatically if I'd make my `Custom` an instance of  [`Ord`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ord.html) as the sort worked automatically then, but it is not really orderable.

Please comment if you'd like to have an example and expected result. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uh, right after asking the question it hit me like a stroke:

[`comparing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ord.html#v%3acomparing) needs a function that returns an orderable result, not an Ordering or the sorted partial list `[(Int, Custom)]` (which is unorderable):

```
comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering
comparing = on compare
```

So what I had to return is a list of the orderable integers, i.e. just `map fst`. Altogether:

```
sortBy (compare `on` map fst)
  :: Ord a => [[(a, b)]] -> [[(a, b)]]
```

Comment: And that's why the `on` function exists! Handy, huh?